# Pandas: find rows where there are duplicate values in one column and differing values in a second column

Tags: python, pandas

I have reviewed other similar questions, but I cannot find an answer to this.

I have a dataframe df1 as follows:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Item': ['A','B','C','D','A','B','C','D','C'],
               'Side':['TRUE','TRUE','TRUE','TRUE','FALSE','TRUE','FALSE','TRUE','TRUE'],
               'Source':['1a','2b','3c','4d','5e','6f','7g','8h','9j']
              })
```

print df1

```
  Item   Side Source
0    A   TRUE     1a
1    B   TRUE     2b
2    C   TRUE     3c
3    D   TRUE     4d
4    A  FALSE     5e
5    B   TRUE     6f
6    C  FALSE     7g
7    D   TRUE     8h
8    C   TRUE     9j
```

I want to find rows where:
Column 'Item' contains a duplicate but, in those duplicate rows, Column 'Side' has differing values.

For example:

1. there are two rows containing 'A' in column 'Item' and they have the different values in column 'Side'  -- these do comply
2. there are two rows containing 'B' in column 'Item' but they both have the same value in column 'Side' -- these do not comply
3. there are two rows containing 'C' in column 'Item' and they have the different values in column 'Side'  -- these do comply

So the output would be:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Item': ['A','A','C','C','C'],
                   'Side':['TRUE','FALSE','TRUE','FALSE','TRUE'],
                   'Source':['1a','5e','3c','7g','9j']
                  })

print df2

 Item   Side Source
0    A   TRUE     1a
1    A  FALSE     5e
2    C   TRUE     3c
3    C  FALSE     7g
4    C   TRUE     9j
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Do you want any answers that combine Source?

Comment: I think i have what your looking for now, can you check the UPDATE section of my answer? Let me know. Thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, you want [`groupby.filter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.filter.html)
If you want the order shown in your expected output you can also use [`DataFrame.sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html):

```
new_df=df1.groupby('Item').filter(lambda x: x['Side'].nunique()>1 ).sort_values('Item')
print(new_df)
  Item   Side Source
0    A   TRUE     1a
4    A  FALSE     5e
2    C   TRUE     3c
6    C  FALSE     7g
8    C   TRUE     9j
```

Comment: Thanks for helping -- I think your previous answer might have been the one. It will be a bit later now before I'm able to finish checking.

Comment: I have updated the solution to meet the new specifications, please check now:)

Comment: I deleted the previous answer because I didn't think it could have unique elements in the Article column. But this new solution consider that case and I think it is correct

Comment: I get an error message with this version: 'TypeError: filter function returned a Series, but expected a scalar bool'

Comment: If you put your previous solution back up, I can mark it as the answer

Answer (score 1):

We groupby on `Item & Side` and get all the groups who are equal to `1` or see it as, all the `unique` groups:

```
mask = df1.groupby(['Item', 'Side'])['Side'].transform('size').eq(1)
df1[mask].sort_values('Item')
```

```
  Item   Side Source
0    A   TRUE     1a
4    A  FALSE     5e
2    C   TRUE     3c
6    C  FALSE     7g
```

Comment: Thanks very much for the help and the quick response. I am getting an error message: 'AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'notna''

Comment: Thanks for your help. My small example dataframe was intended to be representative of a much larger one. On the larger dataframe, duplicates can exist on many rows. Your suggestion works on the smaller example dataframe, but returns unwanted rows on the larger one.

Answer (score 1):

Use `duplicated` with `keep=False`

```
m1 = ~df1.duplicated(['Item', 'Side'], keep=False)
df1[m1].sort_values('Item').reset_index(drop=True)

Out[191]:
  Item   Side Source
0    A   TRUE     1a
1    A  FALSE     5e
2    C   TRUE     3c
3    C  FALSE     7g
```

Note: this solution also includes any non-duplicated (single value) of column `Item`

---

If you also want to ignore non-duplicated of `Item`. just add one more mask `m2`

Sample df2 (row 8 is non-duplicatd on `Item`):

```
Out[193]:
  Item   Side Source
0    A   TRUE     1a
1    B   TRUE     2b
2    C   TRUE     3c
3    D   TRUE     4d
4    A  FALSE     5e
5    B   TRUE     6f
6    C  FALSE     7g
7    D   TRUE     8h
8    E   True     1h

m1 = ~df2.duplicated(['Item', 'Side'], keep=False)
m2 = df2.duplicated(['Item'], keep=False)
df2[m1 & m2].sort_values('Item').reset_index(drop=True)

Out[201]:
  Item   Side Source
0    A   TRUE     1a
1    A  FALSE     5e
2    C   TRUE     3c
3    C  FALSE     7g
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I don't think duplicated() will work because I need to return all the rows which fit the criteria

Comment: I should have added an extra row to the sample dataframe so that there is a duplicate across 3 rows -- I have just added that to the original post

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple way:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Item': ['A','B','C','D','A','B','C','D'],
                   'Side':['TRUE','TRUE','TRUE','TRUE','FALSE','TRUE','FALSE','TRUE'],
                   'Source':['1a','2b','3c','4d','5e','6f','7g','8h']
                  })

df = df.groupby(['Item','Side'])['Source'].min().reset_index() 
df = df[df.duplicated('Item', keep=False)] 

df
Out[152]: 
  Item   Side Source
0    A  FALSE     5e
1    A   TRUE     1a
3    C  FALSE     7g
4    C   TRUE     3c
```

Or if you want to keep them:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Item': ['A','B','C','D','A','B','C','D'],
                   'Side':['TRUE','TRUE','TRUE','TRUE','FALSE','TRUE','FALSE','TRUE'],
                   'Source':['1a','2b','3c','4d','5e','6f','7g','8h']
                  })

df = df.groupby(['Item','Side'])['Source'].min().reset_index() 


Out[140]: 
  Item   Side Source
0    A  FALSE     5e
1    A   TRUE     1a
2    B   TRUE     2b
3    C  FALSE     7g
4    C   TRUE     3c
5    D   TRUE     4d
```

Here's why i combined these, i'm trying to figure out the problem set correctly, so maybe this helps in explaining how to aggregate these:

```
  Item   Side  Source
0    A  FALSE      5e
1    A   TRUE      1a
2    B   TRUE  2b, 6f
3    C  FALSE      7g
4    C   TRUE  3c, 9j
5    D   TRUE  4d, 8h
```

UPDATE:  I think i have what your looking for:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Item': ['A','B','C','D','A','B','C','D','C'],
               'Side':['TRUE','TRUE','TRUE','TRUE','FALSE','TRUE','FALSE','TRUE','TRUE'],
               'Source':['1a','2b','3c','4d','5e','6f','7g','8h','9j']
              })


df = df.groupby(['Item','Side'])['Source'].apply(', '.join).reset_index() 
df = df[df.duplicated('Item', keep=False)] 
df = df.set_index(['Item', 'Side']).apply(lambda x: x.str.split(',').explode()).reset_index()

df

Out[201]: 
  Item   Side Source
0    A  FALSE     5e
1    A   TRUE     1a
2    C  FALSE     7g
3    C   TRUE     3c
4    C   TRUE     9j
```

Comment: I don't think duplicated() will work because I need to return all the rows which fit the criteria. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I should have added an extra row to the sample dataframe so that there is a duplicate across 3 rows -- I have just added that to the original post

Comment: Can you look at the aggregated data at the bottom of my post, I would remove B and D, then split 'C True'. is that the right? I can do that if that's what's needed

Comment: I tested mine against the other solutions, and i think this one hits the problem set head on, let me know

Comment: Your result looks right, but I get an error message: 'AttributeError: ("'Series' object has no attribute 'explode'", u'occurred at index Source')'

Comment: I'm running In import pandas as pd, [346]: pd.__version__                                                                                                                                                                                  
 : '0.25.3'  and python 3.7.2.  Can you let me know your version updated as mine? I tried rerunning, it works in 0.25.3